# How to load a kml file as string in Openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a String variable whose content is KML. I want to load this string and display the kml features in the map. (Openlayers 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass string variable to this function `ol.format.KML.readFeatures(String)`

[Click here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.format.KML.html?unstable=true) for more details